# Is there a solution to this freecell game, shown below?

Tags: free-cell

[image]

Encoding:

```
4D AH TS 3S 5C 4C KD
3C 5H TC 5D TD JD 2C
7H 6D AC 5S 7D 2S 2H
4H 9S AD 9H 9D QC 7C
6C 3D QH 8S 3H KH
QS 8C 2D 4S 9C KS
6S 7S 6H 8H 8D JS
JC QD KC TH AS JH
```

Comment: Probably not. This solver found no solution in 132,000 iterations: https://fc-solve.shlomifish.org/js-fc-solve/text/

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded an open source solver and attempted to solve this, but it was unable to using any of its different algorithms.

```
c:\Program Files\Freecell Solver 6.2.0\bin>fc-solve -t -m c:\files\fc.txt
I could not solve this game.
Total number of states checked is 133770.
This scan generated 133770 states.

c:\Program Files\Freecell Solver 6.2.0\bin>fc-solve -t -m -me dfs c:\files\fc.txt
I could not solve this game.
Total number of states checked is 133770.
This scan generated 133770 states.

c:\Program Files\Freecell Solver 6.2.0\bin>fc-solve -t -m -me bfs c:\files\fc.txt
I could not solve this game.
Total number of states checked is 133770.
This scan generated 133770 states.

c:\Program Files\Freecell Solver 6.2.0\bin>fc-solve -t -m -me patsolve c:\files\fc.txt
I could not solve this game.
Total number of states checked is 198952.
This scan generated 1 states.

c:\Program Files\Freecell Solver 6.2.0\bin>fc-solve -t -m -me soft-dfs c:\files\fc.txt
I could not solve this game.
Total number of states checked is 133770.
This scan generated 133770 states.

c:\Program Files\Freecell Solver 6.2.0\bin>fc-solve -t -m -me a-star c:\files\fc.txt
I could not solve this game.
Total number of states checked is 133770.
This scan generated 133770 states.

c:\Program Files\Freecell Solver 6.2.0\bin>fc-solve -t -m -me random-dfs c:\files\fc.txt
I could not solve this game.
Total number of states checked is 133770.
This scan generated 133770 states.
```